# Create bean with name of a datasource programmatically in Spring Boot

Tags: java

I want to add this bean programmatically:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource2")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.multitenancy.datasource2")
public DataSource dataSource2() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

After googling I found a code and then i applicate it on my case

```
@Autowired 
DataSource dts;
public DataSource datw(){
    new RelaxedDataBinder(dts, "spring.multitenancy.datasource2").bind(DataSourceBuilder.create().build());
}
```

But the problem is that the method bind is not applicable for the argument DataSource. Can you give me a solution for this problem without forgotten bean name?

Comment: "please i want to add programatically this bean". ??? I don't get it. Programmatically adding this bean is exactly what the @Configuration class in the above listing does. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add del log error that you're getting. Have you try with autowire ? or getting the the bean from the application context ?

Comment: yes you are right i want say that i want add this bean dynamically because i will add a lot of datasource dynamically to my application properties  take a look at this

Comment: http://anakiou.blogspot.com/2015/08/multi-tenant-application-with-spring.html  so each datasource in application properties will have  its own bean , how can i do it ?  and thanks @jason